# Java help needed storing the public and private keys in a local file (.txt)

Tags: java, android, encryption, rsa

I'm kinda new to thisand what I'm trying to do is store those private and public keys so that they don't regenerate every time i open the app if that's how it's supposed to be. Thank you to anyone who knows how to help.
i don't where to put FileOutputStream to store
and Files.readAllBytes to read

Comment: This is what the Java [`KeyStore`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/security/KeyStore.html) class is for.

Comment: Generally you should avoid storing keys - especially private keys - as text. However, if you must, you can use .PEM format. Bouncy Castle has PEM parsers / writers.